# Flutter - Overlay drawer icon over WebView

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show the drawer icon in front of the `WebView` page with no `AppBar`.

Here is my Implementation so far:

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: const SafeArea(
    child: WebView(
      initialUrl: "https://sohozeto.com/",
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted)),
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        const DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: Text('Drawer Header'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Item 1'),
          onTap: () {},
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Item 2'),
          onTap: () {
            // Update the state of the app.
            // ...
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: So you want an icon overlay on the Webview and also hide the Appbar?

Comment: yes, how can I get it?

Comment: Your scaffold has no appbar, do you mean the system status bar?

Answer (score 0):

for the overlay, use a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
const SafeArea(
  child: 
      Stack(children: [ 
        ..., // Webview, etc.
        Icon(your_icon),
])
```